# Inserting Multiple Double Quotes In A Cell Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following formula that I want to insert into a cell but it has multiple double quotes and I can't seem to make it work. There is plenty of solutions on the web but most have 1 or 2 sets of double quotes. I tried double quotes on all double quotes but it gives me a runtime error 438 object doesn't support this property

## Here is the formula that I want to insert:

```
="Closing Costs" & " Current Buffer" & " " &TEXT('Closing Costs'!D32,"$ 0")
```

## Here is the code that is not working:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F18").Value = "=""Closing Costs"" &   ""                             
Current Buffer"" & "" "" &TEXT('Closing Costs'!D32,""$ 0"")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work (all on one line):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F18").Value = "=""Closing Costs"" &   ""                             Current Buffer"" & "" "" &TEXT('Closing Costs'!D32,""$ 0"")"
```

It *looks* the same as your sample - but perhaps looks here are deceptive.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `chr()` command can be helpful in these scenarios.      `chr(34)` returns a double quote character, so the below should do the trick.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F18").Value = "=" & chr(34) & "Closing Costs                Current Buffer" & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & TEXT('Closing Costs'!D32," & chr(34) & "$ 0" & chr(34) & ")"
```

It’s a little bit longer, but I find using `chr(34)` to be a little easy to determine quotation placement.